# BigQuery - How to count the occourences against individual record and then group them

Tags: google-bigquery

My table looks like this:

[image: TableA]

I want to output another table like this:

[image: TableB]

I then want to create another table that gives me output like this:

[image: TableC]

I managed to work on the first part with this query:

```
SELECT
  consumerID,
  count (distinct Action) AS TotalUniqueAction
FROM
  [project:database.table]
GROUP BY
  consumerID
```

But now I am lost for the second table.

Comment: have you at least tried something?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I updated the first part of the need in the question. I anticipated that comment from you by the way :)

Comment: i think you were half way through  - see my answer :o) make sure you are using standard sql - not legacy! in legacy sql - count(distinct column) gives estimated / approximate count (just as fyi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN TotalUniqueActions = 1 THEN 'Completed 1 Activity'
    WHEN TotalUniqueActions = 2 THEN 'Completed 2 Activity'
    WHEN TotalUniqueActions > 2 THEN 'Completed 3+ Activity'
  END AS ActionRange,
  COUNT(DISTINCT consumerID) UniqueCustomers
FROM (
  SELECT consumerID, COUNT(DISTINCT Action) TotalUniqueActions
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY consumerID
)
GROUP BY ActionRange
```

if to apply to dummy data in your question  - above wold return below result

```
ActionRange                 UniqueCustomers  
Completed 2 Activity        1    
Completed 3+ Activity       1
```